# different sidebars for different taxonomy vocabularies

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, blocks, theming

I have few blocks I would like to show in sidebar of term page but not for all taxonomy term, only for a certain vocabulary. I can write taxonomy/term/* but it will appear the block on all term pages. Is there a way to limit it by certain vocabulary?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) installed then go to the `admin/config/search/path/patterns` (You find this when in the URL Aliases in the Admin, There would we tab named as Patters)

There you can define a pattern for each vocabulary. Set different url patterns for each of the vocabulary and then you should be able to use than in the block configuration.

Please note that you would have to do bulk update on taxonomy before the urls can take effect on existing terms.

OR

You could use the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module with has much more control over what to display. You can create a context of the type Taxonomy Term and select the vocabularies you want the block to be shown when that condition is true display the required blocks.

Comment: I thought about this, but I would like to have different urls associated with term name, like "city", "nikon"... and that's why this method doesn't work :(

Comment: what would the url patter you have?

Comment: I have updated my answer with one more option. Let me know if that helps